# How do I create a native looking modal view segue with react-native?

Tags: react-native

Is there an way to perform a modal segue, animating the view and navbar up from the bottom, covering the existing navbar, view and tabbar, etc. ?

There is a similar example in UIExplorer where the view 
'Navigator' uses 'configureScene' to float a view (but not the navbar) from bottom via Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom, etc. Native app modal segues are supposed to animate the new navbar and view up from the bottom. Note: A good example of this is the health app, click on 'medical ID' tab, then tap on 'Edit' button in navbar, and notice  how its navbar and view animates and covers the existing navbar, tabbar and view.

I can see a modal segue in the facebook groups app, which is react-native from my understanding. Clicking on the 'Groups' tab, the click on the 'create' navbar button.

Does anyone know how to implement a native modal segues in react-native?

Comment: [starting from v0.10 there's a Modal component](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/ModalExample.js)

Comment: @syg the docs say it is for mixing RN and native parts of an application.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    title: 'Pick Date',
    sceneConfig: Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom,
    component: DatePickerView,
    navigationBar: <NavigationBar
        title="Initial View"/>,
    passProps: {handleSelectedDate: this.handleSelectedDate}
})
```

Link to source is here: https://github.com/aaronksaunders/React-Modal-Nav-Example

Comment: Struggling with this as well. Do you have a complete example somewhere?

Comment: I posted a more complete example here for one approach using a module. aaronksaunders/React-Modal-Nav-Example http://bit.ly/1JCRE6y

Answer (score 3):

I work on the React Native Navigator component.

To accomplish this, you can put a Navigator within the scene of another Navigator. The outside navigator configures its scene with `Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom` or something similar. Inside the scene, you can have another `<Navigator>` with `navigationBar={<Navigator.NavigationBar ...etc />}`

Comment: can you be a bit more specific here? Kinda hard to follow this and it seems like a basic requirement that does not seem to be documented clearly anywhere.

Comment: figured it out myself

Comment: Apologies if the documentation is sparse right now. I have been focusing on stabilizing the API and building features for Android apps. If you want to help clarify the documentation for others, feel free to submit a PR: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/Navigator.js