# Modal View in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native, I am trying to present a view modally. I have a table view and when one of the rows is clicked I want the view to show up modally.

This is how I am implementing the transition right now :

```
renderbooks(books) {
     return (
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.showbooksDetail(books)}  underlayColor='#dddddd'>
              <View>
                  <View style={styles.container}>

                      <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                          <Text style={styles.title}>{books.title}</Text>



                          </View>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.separator} />
              </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
     );
 }
 showbooksDetail(books){
   this.props.navigator.push({
     title:books.title,
     component: ProductView,
     passProps:{books}
   });
 }
```

How can I modify this so that the view can be presented modally?

FYI: I have already looked at multiple questions and sample projects such as these:

- [How do I create a native looking modal view segue with react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379751/how-do-i-create-a-native-looking-modal-view-segue-with-react-native)
- http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html#content
- https://github.com/aaronksaunders/React-Modal-Nav-Example

Answer (score 4):

Check out the built-in [`Modal`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html). It's implemented on iOS, Android implementation should come in one of the next releases of React Native.

The documentation contains an example on how to use it.

In your case it would be something like:

```
renderBooks(books) {
   ...
   <Modal
      animated={true}
      transparent={true}
      visible={!!this.state.selectedBook}>
      <Text>{this.state.selectedBook.title}</Text>
   </Modal>

   ...
}

showDetail(book) {
    this.setState({
        selectedBook: book,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this simple and powerful small library react-native-modal-animated, simply install it by yarn add react-native-modal-animated, or npm install react-native-modal-animated.

```
import { AnimatedModal } from 'react-native-modal-animated
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({ modalVisible: true });
            alert
          }}
          style={styles.button}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Show Modal</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>


        <AnimatedModal
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onBackdropPress={() => {
            this.setState({ modalVisible: false });
          }}
          animationType="vertical"
          duration={600}
        >
          {/*Any child can be used here */}
          <View style={styles.modalCard}>
            <Text>I'm AnimatedModal</Text>
            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 10}}>vertical</Text>
          </View>
        </AnimatedModal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using the react-native modalbox. Its been awesome you get modals to be displayed in top,center,bottom,etc.Check the below link once:https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox

Sample:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Modal from 'react-native-modalbox';
    import Button from 'react-native-button';

    import {
      AppRegistry,
      Text,
      StyleSheet,
      ScrollView,
      View,
      Dimensions
    } from 'react-native';

    class Example extends React.Component {

      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          isOpen: false,
          isDisabled: false,
          swipeToClose: true,
          sliderValue: 0.3
        };
      }

      onClose() {
        console.log('Modal just closed');
      }

      onOpen() {
        console.log('Modal just openned');
      }

      onClosingState(state) {
        console.log('the open/close of the swipeToClose just changed');
      }

    render() {    
        return (
          <View style={styles.wrapper}>
            <Button onPress={() => this.refs.modal1.open()} style={styles.btn}>Basic modal</Button>
            <Button onPress={() => this.refs.modal2.open()} style={styles.btn}>Position top</Button>
            <Button onPress={() => this.refs.modal3.open()} style={styles.btn}>Position centered + backdrop + disable</Button>
            <Button onPress={() => this.refs.modal4.open()} style={styles.btn}>Position bottom + backdrop + slider</Button>

        <Modal
              style={[styles.modal, styles.modal1]}
              ref={"modal1"}
              swipeToClose={this.state.swipeToClose}
              onClosed={this.onClose}
              onOpened={this.onOpen}
              onClosingState={this.onClosingState}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Basic modal</Text>
                <Button onPress={() => this.setState({swipeToClose: !this.state.swipeToClose})} style={styles.btn}>Disable swipeToClose({this.state.swipeToClose ? "true" : "false"})</Button>
            </Modal>
        <Modal style={[styles.modal, styles.modal2]} backdrop={false}  position={"top"} ref={"modal2"}>
                  <Text style={[styles.text, {color: "white"}]}>Modal on top</Text>
                </Modal>

                <Modal style={[styles.modal, styles.modal3]} position={"center"} ref={"modal3"} isDisabled={this.state.isDisabled}>
                  <Text style={styles.text}>Modal centered</Text>
                  <Button onPress={() => this.setState({isDisabled: !this.state.isDisabled})} style={styles.btn}>Disable ({this.state.isDisabled ? "true" : "false"})</Button>
                </Modal>

                <Modal style={[styles.modal, styles.modal4]} position={"bottom"} ref={"modal4"}>
                  <Text style={styles.text}>Modal on bottom with backdrop</Text>

        </Modal>
      </View>
        );
      }

    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      modal: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      },

      modal2: {
        height: 230,
        backgroundColor: "#3B5998"
      },

      modal3: {
        height: 300,
        width: 300
      },

      modal4: {
        height: 300
      },

      wrapper: {
          paddingTop: 50,
    flex: 1
  },

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Example', () => Example);
```