# React Native Modal with transparent using Navigator without using Modal

Tags: react-native

React Native documentation says RN apps should rather use Navigator to create Modals (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html#content).

How can I create a transparent modal using Navigator, without using Modal? I'd like the user to see the current page in the background. Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue.  The recommended way is not really possible for a lot of use-cases.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about the transparent modal, you could use an rgba background-color, for example rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), and pass an alpha to the last argument of the color: rgba(r, g, b, alpha).

As far as the Navigator is concerned, you can use the Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom argument to the navigator to create the modal, placing the modal Navigator within the scene of another Navigator. There is a good thread with examples for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379751/how-do-i-create-a-native-looking-modal-view-segue-with-react-native). Something like:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    title: 'title',
    sceneConfig: Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom,
    component: component,
    navigationBar: <NavigationBar
        title="Initial View"/>,
    passProps: {}
})
```

I've created a sample project with a transparent background [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/pHqjhQ), and placed the code below. I hope this helps!

https://rnplay.org/apps/pHqjhQ

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  Modal,
  StyleSheet,
  SwitchIOS,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,
  AppRegistry,
} = React;

exports.displayName = (undefined: ?string);
exports.framework = 'React';
exports.title = '<Modal>';
exports.description = 'Component for presenting modal views.';

var Button = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      active: false,
    };
  },

  _onHighlight() {
    this.setState({active: true});
  },

  _onUnhighlight() {
    this.setState({active: false});
  },

  render() {
    var colorStyle = {
      color: this.state.active ? '#fff' : '#000',
    };
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        onHideUnderlay={this._onUnhighlight}
        onPress={this.props.onPress}
        onShowUnderlay={this._onHighlight}
        style={[styles.button, this.props.style]}
        underlayColor="#a9d9d4">
          <Text style={[styles.buttonText, colorStyle]}>{this.props.children}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
});

var ModalExample = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      animated: true,
      modalVisible: false,
      transparent: true,
    };
  },

  _setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  },

  render() {
    var modalBackgroundStyle = {
      backgroundColor: this.state.transparent ? 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' : '#f5fcff',
    };

    return (
      <View>
        <Modal
          animated={this.state.animated}
          transparent={this.state.transparent}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}>
          <View style={[styles.container, modalBackgroundStyle]}>
            <View style={[styles.innerContainer]}>
              <Button
                onPress={this._setModalVisible.bind(this, false)}
                style={styles.modalButton}>
                Close
              </Button>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
        <View style={{ marginTop:60 }}>
            <Button onPress={this._setModalVisible.bind(this, true)}>
            SHOW MODAL
            </Button>                             
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ModalExample', () => ModalExample);

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },
  innerContainer: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    flex: 1,
    height: 44,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    margin: 5,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  modalButton: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! I dont think I asked the question clearly, I wanted to know whether it was possible to create a modal using Navigator and View, without using Modal component at all (as Facebook discourages it). I've tried passing alpha to View, but it seems like using Navigator FloatFromBottom automatically covers up the initial component?

Comment: Have you tried passing the alpha to the navigator component directly as a style?

Comment: Hi, just tried:
-
this.props.navigator.push({
      component: Component,
      title: 'Test',
      sceneConfig: Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom,
      navigationBar: <Navigator.NavigationBar style={{backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'}}/>
    })
-
but is not working here?

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer the question.  He's asking about how to not use the <Modal> but instead use Navigator.

Comment: The question was changed from the original. @Udi

Answer (score 1):

To answer the updated question, all you need to do is change your configureScene to something like this:

```
configureScene(route, routeStack){
  if(route.type == 'Modal') {
    return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom
  }
  return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight 
}
```

Then, pass the type of 'Modal' when wanting a modal:

```
_navigate(name, type='Normal') {
  this.props.navigator.push({
    component: Home,
    passProps: {
      name: name
    },
    type: type
  })
}
```

There is an example set up [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/ALL-Sw).

https://rnplay.org/apps/ALL-Sw

Comment: thank you, I know that you can use different scene config to make different animations, but the main problem is how to make modal transparent (i.e. I can see "original screen").

Answer (score 0):

While this does not apply to your case as I used a `Modal`, I'd just like to inform how I achieved a *transparent background* with that:

- in your `render` method where you are rendering `Modal`, pass a `prop` `transparent={true}`
- add a single `View` child to your `modal` (put all other things inside this `View`) and apply a `style` to it with `backgroundColor = 'rgba(r, g, b, a)'`. Here `a` refers to *alpha or opacity level* that you want in the background

`React-Native v0.46.4`

---

See links:

[react-native-router-flux issue #749](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/749)

[react-native issue #2386](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2386)